# Real and imaginary parts of derivative of complex velocity in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, complex-numbers, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Just by chance, I noticed that for an ideal fluid which has a complex velocity say $w=u-iv$, that its derivative with respect to $z=x+iy,$ when written out in real and imaginary parts, looks like

$$\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(u-iv)=\frac12\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-i\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\right]$$

I recognise the imaginary part as the shearing rate tensor up to a sign,

$$S=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$$

and I notice that the real part can be written as $\partial u/\partial x=-\partial v/\partial y$ (since the fluid is ideal and therefore has no divergence), but it feels as though this should have some similar sort of physical interpretation, given that the imaginary part is the shear rate.

My questions are:

1. Does the real part also have a name and physical significance like how the shearing rate is the imaginary part?
2. Is there any physical intuition behind this that makes it 'clear' why the derivative of the complex velocity should give you these terms as real and imaginary parts?

Comment: In this scenario, is the complex part used just to indicate a ninety degree rotation or is it related to growth/decay of some instability (e.g., Kelvin-Helmholtz)?

Comment: In any 2 dimensional flow of an ideal fluid, we can represent the velocity as a complex function $u-iv$, and the 2d coordinates as the complex variable $z$. I haven't assumed any particular physical situation beyond having zero divergence and vorticity. So it's just the usual definition.